# Using if/else in stored procedure with calculation

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures, economics

In my stored procedure i am now trying to add FEE to my sales.

- If the item_price is > 69 it should have 6 in fee
- If the item_price is <= 69 it should have 3 in fee
- If the item_price is <= 19 it should have fee 1

I have tried adding it to my SELECT statement, but i dont know how to insert it properly.

```
   AS 'Income inc VAT, ex Discount',
   case when item_price > 69 then 6
   case when item_price <= 69 then 3
   else 1
   AS 'fee'
```

To give an example on how im trying to implement it, i have added some of the select statement...

Solution: 
Inside my select statement i added this code based on the great answers i got, and it worked:

```
       case when item_price > 69 then 6 
       when item_price <= 69 then 3 
       else 1
       end
       AS 'Fee'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use case statment:

Writing from memory:

```
insert into fee (fee_value)
select 
  case when item_price > 69 then 6
  case when item_price <= 69 then 3
  else 1
end
```

And so on...

Or, maybe you want to use variable:

```
declare @fee int

if @item_price > 69 
 set @fee = 6
```

...

```
insert into fee(fee_value) 
values (@fee)
```

Or another way:

```
declare @item_price int  = 12

declare @fee int

SELECT
  @fee = case 
           when @item_price > 69 then 6
           when @item_price between 13 and 69 then 2
           else 1
         end

select @fee
```

Comment: For this i will have to create a fee column in DB first? Im not getting how to build this into my select statement

Comment: @Lebowski I don't know what you realy want to do.. And I don't know how you want to use your calculation. My solution shows how you can condition fee calculation.

Comment: @Lebowski If you only want to SELECT fee you can use my first example without INSERT part of statment

Comment: case when item_price > 69 then 6
           case when item_price <= 69 then 3
           else 1
           AS 'fee'

Comment: Add SELECT before and you have what you want. Or see edited answer

Comment: Hey, i updated my example. Im getting error:  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'"

Comment: you dont need the second 'case'.  Try 'case when item_price > 69 then 6   when item_price <= 69 then 3'

Comment: @Lebowski CASE keyword should be use only once. And after "1" you have to add END

Comment: Great replies guys, it worked out! Ill add it to my question. Thanks

Comment: Documentation for case statment: http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms181765.aspx